# Excel VBA SeriesCollection_Run time error 1004_parameter not valid

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

Thanks @Rory! I was able to fix it and now I got a new bug
Run time error 1004/parameter not valid
at at .SeriesCollection(j).XValues = ws.Range(rs)

Could someone please help me?

'''
I am trying to make multiple charts. And each chart would have 20 different groups with legend.

The way I have tried is first make multiple charts by columns and then add for/n loop in my code (here tried to have every 20 rows for one each group

```
Sub horizontal()

Dim sh As Shape
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ch As Chart
Dim rd As Range
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

Set ws = Sheets("S1")
On Error Resume Next
    ws.ChartObjects.Delete
On Error GoTo 0

For i = 20 To 45
        Set rs = ws.Range("s2:s21")
        Set rd = ws.Range("f1:j10")
        Set sh = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterLines)
        Set ch = sh.Chart
       
        For j = 1 To 20
            k = j * 20
           
            With ch     'shape.chart'
                .SetSourceData Union(rs, ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, i), ws.Cells(21, i)))
                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .SeriesCollection(j).XValues = ws.Range("s2:s21")
                .SeriesCollection(j).Values = ws.Range(ws.Cells(k - 18, i), ws.Cells(k + 1, i))
                .HasTitle = True
                .ChartTitle.Text = ws.Range("T1")
                .HasLegend = True
            End With
        Next j
       
       
        With sh
            .Name = "cht" & (i - 19)
            .Top = (i - 20) * rd.Height
            .Left = rd.Left
            .Width = rd.Width
            .Height = rd.Height
        End With
Next i
End Sub
```

I tried the below two codes but they didn'twork.

```
Sub horizontal()

Dim sh As Shape
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ch As Chart
Dim rd As Range
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

Set ws = Sheets("S1")
On Error Resume Next
    ws.ChartObjects.Delete
On Error GoTo 0

For i = 20 To 45
        Set rs = ws.Range("s2:s21")
        Set rd = ws.Range("f1:j10")
        Set sh = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterLines)
        Set ch = sh.Chart
       
        
        With ch     'shape.chart'
            .SetSourceData Union(rs, Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(21, i)))
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = ws.Range("T1")
            .HasLegend = True
        End With
       
       
       
        With sh
            .Name = "cht" & (i - 19)
            .Top = (i - 20) * rd.Height
            .Left = rd.Left
            .Width = rd.Width
            .Height = rd.Height
        End With
Next i
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub diameter()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Shape
Dim ch As Chart
Dim rng As Range, rngTime As Range

Dim n As Integer, m As Integer, k As Integer, i As Integer

Set ws = Sheets("S1")

'delete previous plots
If ws.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
    ws.ChartObjects.Delete
End If
   
    Set rngTime = ws.Range(Cells(2, 19), Cells(21, 19))
   
    ws.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterLines).Select
    ws.Shapes(1).Chart.SetSourceData Union(rngTime, Range(Cells(2, 20), Cells(21, 20)))
    'Source:=Range("'S1'!$S$2:$S$21,'S1'!$T$2:$T$21")
       
        For n = 1 To 20
            m = n * 20
           
            With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(n).XValues = ws.Range(Cells(2, 19), Cells(21, 19))
            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(n).Values = ws.Range(Cells(m - 18, 20), Cells(m + 1, 20))
            End With
        Next n
       


End Sub
```

'''

Comment: Posting a lot of code and saying it doesn't work is not a good way to get the help you need. Post an [mcve] and describe precisely the problems with your current code.

Comment: At a minimum, use: `Union(rs, ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, i), ws.Cells(21, i)))`

Comment: And also: `.SeriesCollection(j).Values = ws.Range(ws.Cells(k - 18, i), ws.Cells(k + 1, i))` where you had a bracket in the wrong place.

Comment: My apologies @SJR. I haven't done proper coding before and this is my first question on this website. I will try with Rory's comments and post minimal reproducible example. Thank you!

Comment: @Hi Rory! Thank you so much! Now I got a bug at 'SeriesCollection(j).XValues=ws.Range(rs)' I changed with SeriesCollection(j).XValues=ws.Range(ws.Cells(2,19), ws.Cells(2,21)) still got a bug on the line

Comment: "got a bug" is not a useful description of the problem(s) you're having.  If you get an error when running your code then telling us what the exact error is will always be the best approach to getting help.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm sorry. I got Method 'Range' of Object'_Worksheet' failed. I think it has something to do with range of Xvalues and values but  I don't know fix it

Comment: `.SeriesCollection(j).XValues = rs` presumably.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you! Still got the same error message saying "Method 'Range' of Object'_Worksheet' failed"

Comment: On what line? There's no `Range` call in the line I mentioned.

Comment: @BigBen I'm sorry. I might misunderstood your comments but  I have this on my module Set rs = ws.Range("s2:s21") under For i =

Comment: What is the specific line of code that throws the error?